# What is preventing people from using someone else's CAPTCHA as their own?

Tags: captcha

Why (other than moral reasons) don't more people use the CAPTCHAs of other sites as their own while selling the solving of said CAPTCHAs?

To me, such a system seems like it would be simple to implement:

> - set up a script that does something on another website that requires a CAPTCHA to be completed through the use of a proxy service
> - when a user on your site performs a task that requires the completion of a CAPTCHA, simply serve them the CAPTCHA that the other
>     site asks you to solve
> - when the user solves the CAPTCHA, your script can perform the desired action on the other site that is the source of the CAPTCHA,
>     and the user on your site is also verified through this process

Is this commonplace? If not, why not? What, if anything, could be done to prevent this?

Comment: I don't know, but if you're a legit captcha user, then doing this is like shooting yourself in the foot.

Answer (score 0):

**Fetching the captcha.** Assuming one could easily fetch the exact visual of the captcha from the foreign host. To do this, you have to pass the referral check (*most browsers (navigated by humans) allow to send the `http_referer`*). You also would have to save the `session_id` and the `secret` from the `hidden input`.
**Checking the result.** The foreign host must link the saved variables with the ones associated with the session of your first request, which requires you to implement tricky `cURL` methods. You would have to handle multiple parallel requests, all from your single ip.

Your server will probably use more resources when hacking a captcha on a foreign host than if it generates a captcha on its own.

Prevents

1. http_referer check
2. limit requests for single IP to e.g. 5 / minute
3. good session handling and tricky cookies
4. it's not impossible to reverse engineer javascript, but the more complicated your javascript is, ...
5. you have to find a pattern that recognizes the result on the foreign host. the easiest signature may be the `Location` header field, leading either to `/path/success.html` or `/path/tryagain.php`

**Challenge:**

I took a moment to prepare an example: http://woisteinebank.de/test/

In this example, I attach keys to the `session_id();` and save it in the database.
Through `session_regenerate_id();` I have a fresh session on every request.
In `check.php`, I compare the database values to the `$_GET` values.

Try to find a way to get leech this captcha, I'll try to defend. Everytime you sucessfully use my captcha on your site, I try to defend it.

Comment: what's preventing a screenshot being taken?

Comment: give me a few minutes for a demonstration

Comment: Thanks for the example Dan, but I don't see how this prevents what I'm talking about. The session would not change, unless I'm missing something here (apologies if I am)

Comment: I see your update Dan. While I think you have some interesting ideas, I believe you're misunderstanding what I mean by "serving the image" to a user on the site. What I mean is that the script / program (which could use a proxy service such as Tor) would copy the image and then serve it out to a user to solve. Once the information is solved, the solution is then input by that same script. In this case, session IDs are completely irrelevant, as they have nothing to do with solving the CAPTCHA. While it may be more resource intensive, solving CAPTCHAs can be profitable, eg: spamming

Comment: Unfortunately I'm a bit busy as of late, but when I get some time I'll try to put some sort of example up on Github

Comment: I think I get what you mean, but there are many circumstances preventing you to effectively abuse captchas. Bind the IP to the session, request captcha through tor, upon submitting to solve it with a different ip => invalid request. It might everything be possible, but not in a way to effectively abuse captchas. Still an interesting question! Hope others will contribute their ideas too.